# SSL issue in domain with www

Tags: ssl, nginx, redirect, amazon-ec2, https

I have issues in SSL configuration and I have deployed my web applications to AWS EC2.
For the server, I am using Ngnix.

```
1. http://example.com
2. http://www.example.com
3. https://example.com
4. https://www.example.com
5. example.com
6. www.example.com
```

In the above URLs, only No.4 (https://www.example.com) is not working.
I've got an error - "Your connection is not private".

I use `letsencrypt` for an SSL certificate.
I have 4 sub-domains - `admin.example.com`, `api.example.com`, `dashboard.example.com`, and `admin-api.example.com`.
These work perfectly.

I've created an SSL for each sub-domains but didn't create an SSL certificate for `www.example.com`

Below is my Ngnix configuration file.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.example.com;
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        server_name example.com;  
        access_log /var/log/nginx/listing-page.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/listing-page.error.log;
...
        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

I've tried to solve this issue all day but couldn't still fix it.

Comment: `www.example.com` is only configured as HTTP (port 80) in your example and about "I've created an SSL for each sub-domains but didn't create an SSL certificate for www.example.com" that can not work, if this name is not in the certificate a secure connection can not be established so you need a proper certificate. Besides your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Comment: But www.example.com works well. Only https://www.example.com is not working

Comment: "In the above URLs, only No.4 (https://www.example.com) is not working." and "But www.example.com works well."  seems to contradict each others... You may wish to make your question clearer (using real names helps...) and post it on appropriate forums.

Comment: The error simply means that there is no certificate for `www.example.com` which you state in your question. You could create a certificate which accepts both `example.com` and `www.example.com` or create a separate certificate for `www.example.com` and just use it to redirect to `example.com`.